# How to set Focus on a non input element

Tags: html, scroll, focus

I have a script that shows a popup, and fairly often, the content is taller than the window and requires scrolling. The popup box is within a container div that has an overflow so the popup can be scrolled around without interfering with the scroll position on the rest of the page.

The issue is that when the popup box is displayed, when the up and down arrows are pressed, nothing happens as the popup box in the holder is not focused. Only when I click on an element within the container, then the arrows start working. Is it possible to perform a similar function to the 'click on an element' method described before, except in javascript. I tried `.focus` and other similar commands, but none worked.

Comment: how are you creating the popup, jquery-ui one? window.open?

Comment: `container = document.createElement('div')`, `popup = document.createElement('div')`, `popup.innerHtml = '...'`, `container.appendChild(popup)`, `document.body.appendChild(container)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Aha, sorted it. Set the holder's `tabIndex` to `-1` and then `.focus()` worked on selecting it